# Limited partial sum of $\displaystyle \sum _{n=1} ^{k} \cos(nx)$ are limited?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry

I'm wondering if it's true that  $\displaystyle \sum _{n=1} ^{k} \cos(nx)$ has limited partial sum.

I know it has representation $\displaystyle \frac{\sin\left(\frac{kx}{2}\right)\cdot\cos\left(\frac{(k+1)x}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}$

and we have it defined for $x \in \mathbb{R}-\{ c\cdot\pi \}$ for some $c \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: What do you mean by limited?

Comment: that there is such constatnt $M$ so that $\displaystyle|  \sum_{n=1} ^{k} \cos(nx)| \le M$

Comment: Then no; take $x=0$.

Comment: Use complex form and Abel's tranformation after take the real part.

Comment: @WilliamStagner you can't take $x=0$ because it's not in the domian

Comment: It's certainly in the domain. Just plug it into the sum.

Comment: no it's not take for $c=0$

Comment: That forumula is not defined for $x=0,$ but the sum is, obviously, with value $k.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certian the numerator is bounded, and the denominator is fixed.  Since $x\ne c\pi$ for any $c\in\Bbb Z$, $\sin x/2\ne 0$.

Hence, 
$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^k\cos nx\right|\le\frac 1{\sin x/2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^k\cos(nx)&=Re(\sum_{n=0}^k\mathbb e^{inx})\\
&=\frac{\sin(\frac{kx}{2})\cos(\frac{(k+1)x}{2})}{\sin(\frac{x}2)}
\end{align}
$$
From here: $$\left|\sum_{n=0}^k\cos(nx) \right|=\left|\frac{\sin(\frac{kx}{2})\cos(\frac{(k+1)x}{2})}{\sin(\frac{x}2)} \right|\le \frac{1}{|\sin(\frac{x}2)|}$$

Comment: Seems to me that this just yields the identity he's shown in the question. How does this add something to what he alredy knows?